# keycode for exclamation mark with adb shell input

Tags: android, adb

How can I enter a "!" via adb? I can't find the keycode anywhere and it isn't coming across with I use `adb shell input text !`

```
adb shell input keycode <???>
```

Comment: hmm- `adb shell input text !` seems to work fine for me: just to be clear, that's not working for you? Or have I misunderstood?

Comment: No, not working for me.

Comment: which version of android you are using ? Is it throwing any errors while issuing the command? I am able to enter `!` character via `adb shell input text !`

Comment: I checked again. It seems that the issue is when the ! is the last character run in a batch file: 


`@echo off
adb wait-for-device
adb shell input text xyzabc!`

Comment: This is still not working for me: adb shell input text "!1234" returns -bash: !1234: event not found

Answer (score 4):

you need to escape the following characters:

( ) < > | ; & * \ ~ " '
'escaping' means putting a backslash ( \ ) before the offending character.

space is escaped by using %s

```
adb shell input text \!
```

There is no keycode for !.

Comment: *escaping* means putting the *escape* symbol before the offending character. not every OS/shell uses \ for that purpose

Comment: I also say "space is escaped by using %s" ;O) Were talking about adb shell here.